# Manage Lerna package dependencies in mono repo

Tags: node.js, monorepo, lerna

I have a mono repo that I manage with lerna and has the following structure:

```
root:
  - packages:
      - package_a
      - package_b
      - package_c
```

In the code I have `package_c` as a dependency in `package_a`, so in package_a's `package.json` file I have

```
dependencies: {
    package_c: "1.0.0"
}
```

However, if I want to push a change to all packages, the version update, and my package_a points to an old version of package_c.

Is there a way to make sure `package_a` users the latest version I push of `package_c`? I tried using the latest tag but for some reason it did not work.

I saw that projects like `@wdio` use a link script but can't figure out how it works.

Thank you in advance.